How can I use auto in a template array
I have this template
template<typename T, int N> using raw_array = T[N];
how can I use something like this
auto&& z = raw_array<auto&, 5>{};
the error is: 'auto' is not allowed here.
I've searched around and found nothing so far that's why I m asking.

You can't make an array of references.

And why don't you use the feature that already exists? std::array is a nice class wrapper over C-style arrays that does exactly what you are trying to do.

auto is not what you think it is. If you cannot replace auto with a concrete type, then the compiler certainly cannot do it

btw wrong code is very poor at explaining what it is supposed to mean. The line just wrong and makes no sense. What do you want auto&& z = raw_array<auto&, 5>{}; to be? It should create an array ? of what ?

How should the compiler interpret auto&& z = auto&[5]{} ? What does it even mean?

raw_array<auto&, 5> appears to fix only the N=5 and leave T unspecified. You'd write that as
template<typename T, int N> using raw_array = T[N];
template<typename T> using z = raw_array<T, 5>;

As noted in the comments, you can't have an array of T&.
